# Where can I find an example of creating a FaceTime comparable camera in OSX

Tags: macos, camera, webcam, apple-developer

Many of us are working from home more and I envy the Windows guys who have a virtual webcam plugging in OBS (Open Broadcast Studio).  OBS and the Windows plugin are open source projects.  As a competent software engineer I should be able to create a plugin that works on OSX -But- I am not a hardened OSX dev.

I am sure I am not googling for the correct APIs and Subsystems.  If someone(s) could help me with the Apple concept map to this obscure topic. I would be grateful for a set of crumbs that leads to the OSX API to call(s) to create a camera.  I know it can be done as SnapCam does it, but that is a closed-source app.

I am aware of the workaround for OBS that 
1) uses code injection and requires disabling security features
2) Doesn't even work in the current versions of OSX
3) Requires yet another app running with video previews etc.

I like the challenge of creating this plugin. I am also wise enough to try and ask for a road map if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

Someone beat me to it.  https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam

I thought I would search just githib.com directly with the search "virtual camera macos site:github.com".  Constraining the search to just GitHub was quite useful.